# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' / Base conversions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code and I just don't get this code is not working.

```
def theBase(n, b):
   convertString = "0123456789"
   if n < b:
      return convertString[n]
   else:
      return toBase(n//b,b) + convertString[n%b]

def toBase(n, b):
   print(theBase(n, b), end="")

def main():
    n = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    print(n, "in base", b, "is ", end="")
    toBase(n, b)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Do not modify main function**

Comment: `toBase` doesn't return anything (so it implicitly returns `None`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because the function `toBase()` returns `None` as there is no explicit return statement. Then the last line in function `theBase()` tries to add the return value from `toBase()` (which is None) to a string, which gives you the exception that you see.

I think you have a simple mistake where `theBase()` should be calling itself, not `toBase()` (see last line of that function). The following will fix the problem:

```
def theBase(n, b):
   convertString = "0123456789"
   if n < b:
      return convertString[n]
   else:
      return theBase(n//b,b) + convertString[n%b]
```

Comment: As I mentioned on the bottom, I cannot change anything in main(). Is there any other way that I solve this problem?

Comment: I've updated my answer now that I've realised what the mistake is.

Comment: @정민호: yes, it does print it in `toBase()`. The problem is the last line of your `theBase()` function. It should be calling itself, not calling back to `toBase()`. Just change your `theBase()` function to the one that I show above and all should be well.